# Python: How to output the FASTA header or chromosome index figure according to the location?

Tags: python, loops, bioinformatics, biopython, fasta

I have the code which help me to move the window of size 5 when it moves from left to right. The file is in fasta format with header >chromosome for example followed by the index of the chromosome. I would like to output the header index number according to the exact index. Can anyone help me?

**Code**

```
from Bio import SeqIO

with open("test1_out.fasta","w") as f:
        for seq_record in SeqIO.parse("test1.fasta", "fasta"):
            for i in range(len(seq_record.seq) - 4) :
               f.write(">" + str(seq_record.id) + "\n")
               f.write(str(seq_record.seq[i:i+5]) + "\n")
```

**test1.fasta**

```
>chr1:1-8 
ATCGCGTC
>chr2:1-10
ATTTTCGCGA
```

**Actual output**

```
>chr1:1-8
ATCGC
>chr1:1-8
TCGCG
>chr1:1-8
CGCGT
>chr1:1-8
GCGTC
>chr2:1-10
ATTTT
>chr2:1-10
TTTTC
>chr2:1-10
TTTCG
>chr2:1-10
TTCGC
>chr2:1-10
TCGCG
>chr2:1-10
CGCGA
```

**Desired output**

```
>chr1:1-5
ATCGC
>chr1:2-6
TCGCG
>chr1:3-7
CGCGT
>chr1:4-8
GCGTC
>chr2:1-5
ATTTT
>chr2:2-6
TTTTC
>chr2:3-7
TTTCG
>chr2:4-8
TTCGC
>chr2:5-9
TCGCG
>chr2:6-10
CGCGA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to modify the heading writing:

```
seq_name = seq_record.id.split(":")[0]  # Get the "chr1"
for i in range(len(seq_record.seq) - 4):        
    seq_coords = "{}-{}".format(i + 1, i + 5)  # Make the coordinates

    f.write(">" + seq_name + ":" + seq_coords + "\n")  # Print them both
```